# Array in C and malloc

Tags: c, malloc

1.How the two dimension stored in the memory, are they consecutive? (I mean the int[M][N], not the dynamic allocation, I think the int[M][N] happened in the stack area, so continual, isn't it?)

2.Does the area allocated by malloc must is consecutive?

3.If there is no need to dynamic allocate memory space, where should I use? stack or heap.
For example,
I want a char array to store 10000 chars, so should I use:

```
char a[10000];
```

or

```
char *a = calloc(sizeof(char),10000);
```

Is the "function call stack" in the same area as the variable stack??In the same stack or different?

Comment: One question per question, please. This isn't a "chat forum".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `int numbers[m][n]` the n's are consecutive ints in memory, e.g. `numbers[0][0]` is followed by `numbers[0][1]`.

On the other hand, lets say n=10, then `numbers[m][9]` is followed by `numbers[m+1][0]`.

`malloc` returns consecutive memory. you decide how to use it.

A 10000 byte array on the stack is no problem unless the function is recursive and (as Carey notes) unless you are developing in a small stack environment ie. embedded.

Yes the callstack and local variables are identical.

Comment: A 10K array on the stack _might_ not be a problem, but you can't make that blanket statement.  In some environments it could be a big problem (especially device drivers, embedded systems, etc).

Comment: In embedded malloc'ed 10k is **more** problematic then stack 10k. And i said non-recursive. Also keep in mind OP is a beginner and wants to know about the machine he's developing on.

Comment: Not if you're malloc'ing fixed size blocks, but I won't quibble on that.  You're right that malloc is generally avoided in embedded.  But even with non-recursive functions there are environments where 10K on the stack would definitely be a problem.  I just think you should amend your answer on #2 to not be such a blanket statement.

Answer (score 1):

1. The memory is contiguous. All items in one dimension will be consecutive followed by the next dimension.
2. Yes. All memory allocated by a single call to `malloc()` is contiguous.
3. If you need a lot of memory, I recommend allocating it dynamically. For less memory, you could allocate statically. `malloc()` *does* use the heap. I don't recommend the stack except for only very small amounts of memory.

Comment: To 1), items `int[m][n]` for a fixed m are stored consecutively. The entire array is arranged in memory so that the "index" in memory is computed as `m*N + n`, where N is the size of the second dimension.

Answer (score 1):

#### When you allocate something[a][b] is it contiguous?

Yes

When I made games that had tiled maps I would even access a tile using a pointer in rendering.

Ie: if the map was 10x10, I would render tile [1][3] by using `arrayName[14]` for example.

Also keep in mind using that fact, that in some places, [b] instead of [a] is what will be completely on the memory, this might cause bugs if you are relying on code that came from FORTRAN (like CBLAS) or in some specific devices and situations (like some GPU with some particular drivers).

#### When you use malloc, it must be contiguous?

Yes, and it will fail if contiguous memory is not available.
It is a very common mistake to expect that a program will work because the total free memory exists, without taking in account memory fragmentation.

I made once a game that failed to work because it had 30mb of memory but could not load a 16mb image... I did not realised at the time that memory fragmentation caused by my code was making no block of 16mb be available.

#### If there are no need for dynamic allocation, I should use stack or heap?

In C, dynamic allocation usually means heap allocation anyway, early C books even explicitly say that `malloc` and similar family of functions (`calloc` included) operate only on the heap. while automatic allocation attempts to use the stack.

Answer (score 0):

C does not support 2D arrays.  It supports arrays of arrays and arrays of pointers to arrays, either of which can be use like a 2D array, but they're not at all the same, and neither of them is really a 2D array.

An array occupies contiguous memory locations.  So when you have an array of arrays, each subarray is individually contiguous, and these arrays are laid out in memory one after another, making the whole thing contiguous.

When you have an array of pointers to arrays, each subarray is individually contiguous, but the subarrays don't need to be contiguous with each other -- they might be spread all over memory.  The top level array is contiguous, but it only contains the pointers to the subarrays, not the subbarrays themselves.

In either case, you can get a single (row) subarray out of the '2D' array, but there's no easy way to get a column array -- you need to create a separate array and copy the value out of each individual row array if you want it in that form.

Answer (score -1):

1) I'll be honest, I don't know.

2) Yes, the area allocated by malloc is contiguous *in the virtual address space*. This can be deduced with a simple thought exercise; given a pointer, if you iterate over the full space, you always increment the pointer by one and still get valid data. Note though that it's possible for non-contiguous physical mappings to be returned, although this is all handled at levels below you (i.e. within the operating system and the processor's TLBs).

3) Typically, use the heap. It's generally a larger segment, *especially* if you're using threads (i.e. a test I just ran showed pthreads' default stack size as 8MB).

As for the second part of 3), the function call stack is the same as the variable stack. When you create a variable statically (i.e. not through `malloc`), it exists within the containing function's stack frame, which of course resides on the stack. For more information on this, have a look at the stack convention for .

Comment: Great quote from Lounge<C++> : *If you don't know the answer to a question don't answer it.
It ain't rocket science.*

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I would imagine it's due to #1.  If you don't know, you shouldn't answer.  Also, #2 makes the baseless assumption it's a virtual memory OS.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz That's fair enough, I was trying to add an answer to the other two questions though, I could see the justification if I stumbled into random posts and just said "well, yeah, no idea".

Comment: @CareyGregory - another fair point. In 99% of cases on StackOverflow though, the authors are going to be running on a machine with virtual memory.